# Set up "load more" with JSON results using getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on pulling in objects from a JSON file and placing them into a masonry-like grid using Salvattore. I found [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dynamic-grid-with-salvattore-and-bootstrap-in-10-minutes--cms-20410) which worked great for pulling in the data but now I would like to set up a pagination system. Currently I have it working so that on initial load only 6 objects are returned and populated, but I am not sure how to program the "load more" button so that it appends only the next 6 posts.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function getResults(filter) {
    $.getJSON("results.json", function(data) {
        var perPage = 6;
        var count = data.posts.length;
        $(data.posts).each(function (i, post) {
            if (filter) {
                if (post.source === filter && i < perPage) {
                    populate(post.source, post.permalink, post.content, post.date);
                }
            } else if(i < perPage) {
                populate(post.source, post.permalink, post.content, post.date);
            }
            i = i + 6;
        });
        perPage = perPage + 6;
    });
}
getResults();
```

I'm not entirely sure what the logic should be to set this up so I am just guess/checking right now. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RT23kfIh85vkEG1n3zA0) which has the HTML/Sample JSON and the rest of my JavaScript.

Comment: You will get the data from some file.json or a server back-end who will do a SQL query with pagination?

Comment: The data will be coming from a `.json` file just like in the Plunker example and everything will be done on the front-end, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to send data to your back-end, you'll need to send the page. You can do like this:

```
var currentPage = 1;

function getResults(filter, page) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: {page: currentPage},
        success:  function(data) { ... code here ... }
    });
}

$('.load-more').click(function(e) {
    currentPage++;
    getResults();
});
```

But, if you're goin to show data from a JSON, the browser will download entire JSON in the beginning, so you already have the data, then you can do this:

```
var currentPage = 1;

$('.load-more').click(function(e) {
    currentPage++;
    getResults();
});

function getResults(filter) {
    $.getJSON("results.json", function(data) {
        var perPage = 6;
        var count = data.posts.length;
        if((currentPage-1) * perPage > count)
          alert("all pages fetched");
          return false;
        }
        $(data.posts).each(function (i, post) {
          if(i >= (currentPage -1) * perPage && i < currentPage * perPage) {
            if (filter) {
              if(post.source === filter) {
                populate(post.source, post.permalink, post.content, post.date);
              }
            } else {
                populate(post.source, post.permalink, post.content, post.date);
            }
            i = i + perPage;
          }
        });
        perPage += perPage;
    });
}
```

I've forked your plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/7kn2n9uhBPGZxXDLPLIz?p=preview

There is still one problem, the append function isn't working properly, but maybe it's a bug in your library or the way you are using it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is almost exactly what I'm looking for, unfortunately, in it's current state, it only seems to work if the number of JSON objects are divisible by the `perPage` value. For instance, if I remove all but 7 of the objects and then hit the "load more" button, it says that all pages have been fetched without appending the 7th object. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to show how that would work? Unfortunately I don't have any experience with that function.

Comment: Just edit this line: `if(currentPage * perPage > count)` to `if((currentPage-1) * perPage > count)`

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!